# Executing a Perl file from php

Tags: javascript, php, perl

I am working with Perl and php, and I would like to call a Perl program at some point.
Both of them are in the same folder and I don't need to pass any argument, just execute it.

I don't know if I need to use **JavaScript** or just a

```
exec();
```

doing something like this:

```
$result = exec(perl changePass.pl)
```

I already tried both of them and I wasnt able to execute it.

Comment: The [manual page for exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) describes the function as "Execute an external program". That's a pretty good clue that PHP can actually do it thus you don't need Node or any other technology. However, if you're able to switch languages (i.e., PHP is not a requirement) can't you just do it plain Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to involve JavaScript.

The first argument of [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) needs to be a string. You can't just shove shell commands into the middle of PHP.

```
exec("perl changePass.pl")
```

Ensure that `perl` is on your path (this is likely). Ensure that `changePass.pl` is in the current working directory (this is very likely to not be the case). Alternatively *use full paths* to them.

Comment: Can I just ask (out of curiosity) would any output from the Perl program be output to the webpage that called the script (assuming there is output) ?

Comment: No. That's what the second argument to `exec` is for.